# Formatting only lower case letters

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to format cells where only the lower case letters would be red, all other upper case letters and all numbers would be black.

The cells are the result of a formula, referencing to another page. The cell which it is referenced to is comprised of other formulas within that page.

How do I get my font's formatting to travel with formulas (it would be easy to color the lower case letters red in this instance because I have extracted them into their own cell along the way) OR do you have a suggestion for conditional formatting or code to made only lower case letters red?

Comment: What have you tried? You'll need to loop through each character in each cell and check the case, and apply formatting from there.

Comment: cant do partial colouring of text with formulas.  You can do an all or nothing approach with Conditional formatting.

Comment: Is doable with VBA though, don’t get the wrong idea

Comment: Using VBA, change the formula to a text string; then use the `.Characters` property of the `Range` object to test each character, and format according to your tests.

Answer (score 0):

`"... OR do you have suggestion for ... code to made only lower case letters red"`

Yeah, that would be this, but it's not incredibly efficient

```
Option Explicit

Sub LowercaseToRed()

    SpeedUp True
    On Error GoTo ErrClose

    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Range("A1:D10")

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To cell.Characters.count
            If 97 <= Asc(Mid(cell.Value2, i, 1)) And Asc(Mid(cell.Value2, i, 1)) <= 122 Then
                cell.Characters(i, 1).Font.color = vbRed
            End If
        Next i

    Next cell

ErrClose:
    SpeedUp False

End Sub

Sub SpeedUp(ByVal toggleOn As Boolean)

    With Application
        .Calculation = IIf(toggleOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
        .ScreenUpdating = Not toggleOn
        .DisplayStatusBar = Not toggleOn
        .EnableEvents = Not toggleOn
    End With

End Sub
```